# Using Entity Framework in Azure functions

Tags: c#, entity-framework, azure

I'm trying to create an azure function that needs to access a database. I have a .netstandard 2.0 library that contains all the database stuff (it has `Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools` and `Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer` Nuget packages and created all the related classes with `Scaffold-DbContext`). My azure function (queue triggered) has a reference to that library and it has Nuget packages `Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer` and `Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore`. Everything builds, but when it runs and the queue triggers the functions it complains:

> [1/18/2019 3:53:49 PM] A ScriptHost error has occurred
>
> [1/18/2019 3:53:49 PM] Exception while executing function: MyFunction. MyProcessor: Could not load file or assembly
>   'Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore, Version=2.2.1.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60'. Could not find or load a specific
>   file. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131621). System.Private.CoreLib:
>   Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore,
>   Version=2.2.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60'.

which happens here (because it I just remove the `using` block, then it runs fine, but obviously doesn't do anything useful):

```
[FunctionName("MyFunction")]
public static void Run([QueueTrigger("my-items", Connection = "queueConnection")]string myQueueItem, TraceWriter log)
{
    using (var ctx = new MyDotNetStandardLibary.Models.MyEFContext())
    {
        //...
    }
    log.Info($"C# Queue trigger function processed: {myQueueItem}");
}
```

The `bin` folder does contain `Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.dll` and it looks like it's the right version, so why won't it load it? I had a similar problem with JSON.net, but ended up just giving up on even using it and worked around it. But I need EF. What am I missing about getting an Azure function to load dependencies?

Comment: How are you deploying your function app? Have you seen the following possibly related question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45148517/azure-function-app-ignoring-dependencies

Comment: @mbj: I'm not deploying it at all yet. I'm running it locally in visual studio.

Comment: I'm  not sure I understand... Does your function also depend directly on EF? Or were those Nuget packages added to the function project just because the other library depends on them?

Comment: @mbj - I need to access a database. I made a library to keep all my database access in one place (I actually have regular .NET libraries elsewhere, but had to remake it as .NET Standard 2.0 library, but that's beside the point). My azure function needs to use it, but when it tries to create a database context it will throw the exception shown above.

Comment: Yes, but why did you add EF to your _function app_? Isn't it enough that the database access library has the references to EF?

Comment: * Isn't it enough that the database access library has the references to EF?* - no. This happens with regular .net framework applications too. You can import a library using EF and it will still complain that the application consuming the library doesn't reference EF